# Need help converting this code snippet from c# to vb

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hey i've tried all the online code converters but none of them work on this. Can someone please explain to me how to transform this sniped it to vb.net?

```
yahoo.OnBuddyAddYouRequest += delegate(object sender, string buddy, string requestMessage, ref bool bAccept)
{
    object[] inVar = { sender, buddy, requestMessage,bAccept };
    this.Invoke(new OnBuddyAddYouRequestYahooEventHandler(OnBuddyAddYouRequest), inVar);
    bAccept = (bool)inVar[3];
};
```

Comment: While I know why you probably need it converted, I thought I would mention that all this effort is moot anyway since both code snippets evidently end up as MSIL :D

Comment: what does that mean? i'm confused

Answer (score 2):

Change the inner code to a separate method:

```
private void buddyAddYouRequest(object sender, string buddy,
        string requestMessage, ref bool bAccept)
{
    object[] inVar = { sender, buddy, requestMessage, bAccept };
    this.Invoke(new OnBuddyAddYouRequestYahooEventHandler(OnBuddyAddYouRequest), inVar);
    bAccept = (bool)inVar[3];
}
```

and then change the line you quoted into this:

```
yahoo.OnBuddyAddYouRequest += buddyAddYouRequest;
```

Then you can run this through a code converter to convert it to VB.NET.

However, I should point out that the code makes no sense. It seems to invoke an existing method, `OnBuddyAddYouRequest`, but in an unnecessarily roundabout way. I realise that the author may be trying to overcome multi-threading issues; in that case, you can write it much more simply (and type-safe) like this:

```
private void buddyAddYouRequest(object sender, string buddy,
        string requestMessage, ref bool bAccept)
{
    bool bAcceptCopy = bAccept;
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => OnBuddyAddYouRequest(sender, buddy,
                                 requestMessage, ref bAcceptCopy)));
    bAccept = bAcceptCopy;
}

// ...

yahoo.OnBuddyAddYouRequest += buddyAddYouRequest;
```